# Spatially join two Polygons

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gdal, grass-gis, vector

I have a `shapefile 1` and a `shapefile 2`. `Shapefile 1` contains ~2k Polygons while `shapefile 2` contains ~4k polygons.
I want to know, which Polygons from `shapefile 1` intersect polygons in `shapefile 2`. Further want to write the information from the intersecting polygons into the attributetable from `shapefile 2`, into the corresponding rows of the polygon. I want to preserve the shape/outline of `shapefile 2`! 
One polygon from `shapefile 2` can be intersected by many polygons from `shapefile 1`. That means my resulting shapefile will have way more than ~4k Polygons. Whatever I try though (Intersect/Union) returns me the information I need **BUT** with the outline of `shapefile 1`. I tried a `Spatial Join` but that did not help neither. It did not write multiple information into one polygon in `shapefile 1`. The resulting shapefile from the `spatial join` had as many rows as `shapefile 2`.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS/GRASS/GDAL?

Comment: Have you tried intersecting both polygons and calculating relative area after intersection for each polygon? With that, you can select by ID the intersection with bigger relative area in each object and use`search` in Excel or `lookup(qdap)` in R to merge fields to shapefile 2.

Comment: @aldo_tapia maybe you misunderstood me: I want to write the information from one shapefile into another, where there is an overlap/intersection. That has nothing to do with calculated area or some sort...

Comment: There are two ways to solve this, and Union is one of them, so you probably don't want to refuse a correct answer.

Comment: @Vince I reasked becasue importing something into Excel etc. sounds like a strange workaround. What would the other solution be? Further, `Union` only works if the geometries overlay exactly.

Comment: Probably you need "intersect" from vector -> geoprocessing tools. For more information you can check: http://grindgis.com/software/qgis/basic-editing-tools-in-qgis This will write the intersected polygons into another shape file using the attributes from both shape files.

Comment: The information may be obtainable from a spatial join, though a Union would provide additional details (the difference between Intersects and Intersection in PostgreSQL).

Comment: @Vince thats the thing. With a spatial join, I get as a result ~4k Polygons. Exactly the number of polygons I got in my starting shapefile. That cannot be...

Comment: You seem to be assuming that one-to-many relationships will return the source multiple times, as in a SQL query, but that is not likely to be the case with shapefiles.  If you provide details on what you have tried in the question, then maybe a QGIS person can tell you where it went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You intersect shapefile 1 and shapefile 2 (that would be v.overlay with AND operator in GRASS) and produce shapefile 3.

Then you add a text column to your shapefile 2 where you can upload a e.g. comma separated list of polygon IDs in text form (you can use an array if you DB-backend supports that data type).

Next is to aggregate attributes from shapefile 3:

`CREATE TABLE intersection AS SELECT ID_shapefile_2, group_concat(ID_shapefile_2) FROM shapefile_3 GROUP BY ID_shapefile_2;` ("group_concat" would be an SQLite function). In GRASS you can run this in db.execute

Finally, you join attributes from "intersection" table to shapefile 2.

If prefer a QGIS solution, have a look at expressions and aggregates (but I am not that familiar with those...

BTW: In PostGIS you could do that in one fairly simple query:

`CREATE TABLE result AS SELECT
b.*, array_agg(DISTINCT a."ID") AS shape1_ids FROM
shapefile_1 As a,
shapefile_2 As b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
GROUP BY b.*;`

Comment: Wouldnt the PostGIS solution be `CREATE TABLE table3 AS SELECT t1.a, t1.geom t2.c FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t1.geom);`?

Comment: Not if you want the result to equal shapefile_2 with only on additional column for ids from shapefile_1. The solution you suggest would lead to duplicate rows from both t1 and t2... But i forgot the GROUP BY clause so I fixed that in my answer...

Comment: I posted another question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218135/st-instersects-and-join-result-to-new-table There is a sketch which might make it clearer. Performing my query does not leave me with duplicated rows.