# ST_Instersects and Join result to new table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, table

I am having two tables, `table1` and `table2`.

I want to know which parts of `table2` intersect with `table1`. Having that information, I want to write the attributes from `table2` into `table1` (where they intersect) and create a completely new `table3` of it. I want to preserve the geometry (polygons) from `table1`

[image: sketch]

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
SELECT t1.*, t2.c, t2.d FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t1.geom);
```

Would that give me my desired result?

Comment: Using `SELECT  *` is a violation of best practice when `JOIN`s are involved and you also left out naming the `ST_Intersection ` result.

Comment: @Vince not sure if you saw my updated Q. What do you mean by "naming the `ST_Intersection` result"

Comment: The point being that you don't have one. You should always explicitly name your SELECT columns.

Comment: @Vince So the way I did it is alright? I named the SELECT columns `t1.*, t2.c, t2.d`? Sorry, I am very new to postGIS

Comment: No. Use of `*` is sloppy and dangerous. It also includes the wrong geometry field.

Comment: @Vince. Thanks, so I would need to change to `SELECT t1.a t1.b t1.geom t2.c t2.d`

Comment: No. If you want "where they intersect" you need to use `ST_Intersection()`. Look at the documentation, especially the examples.

Comment: @Vince hanks for sticking with me. Very confusing for me. I think I got it? `CREATE table2 AS SELECT t1.a t1.b t1.geom t2.c t2.d, ST_Intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom) AS intersected FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t1.geom);` But that returns two geometry columns in the resulting `table3`. But I want to preserve `table1` and its geometry and only join the **values** of intersecting features of `table2` onto it

Comment: Could you show with a simple sketch and attribute table what you would like to get as a result?

Comment: st_intersect is a boolean true and false test and will NOT change or manipulate geometry. st_intersection is a computational geometry function and will create a new layer of where the two layers INTERSECT

Comment: i am not sure you question makes sense: you want to "know which parts of table2 intersect with table1" but also just preserve the geometry of table1? ...

Comment: @ziggy I added a sketch

Comment: Syntax error, you have ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t1.geom) and should be ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t2.geom)

Comment: @PaulRamsey thanks for pointing that out. Thats a typo. I abstracted my original code :)